# S3 AWS C++ client Kerberos

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

How do I make aws c++ client use kerberos for S3 calls?

I cannot figure out how to overwrite Authorization header.

Also, don't seem to find a way to set CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE in their curl client(default on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

We don't expose libcurl's internal settings.
You would have to fork the repo and make such modifications. I'm assuming you're using a S3 like API rather than AWS S3?